# show div depends on the number entered in textbox and a button click

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, textbox

I have jQuery Dialog Box and if the user click `#buttonDialog` dialog box will show up and they will be asked for their address and number of their house occupant. My problem is if the user enter a number in `#textHouseOccupant` `#divOccupantProfile` will show up depends on the number entered in `#textHouseOccupant`. For example user enter 5 in `#textHouseOccupant` and clicked the button `#btnAddOccupant`, 5 `#divOccupantProfile` will show up.

**jQuery Dialog Box**

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td><div id="divresident" runat="server" visible="false">
  <table style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px">
  <tr>
    <td width="300" style="text-align:left"><asp:Label ID="lbAddress" runat="server" Text="Address"></asp:Label></td>
    <td width="300"><asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" class="basetxt" runat="server" Width="290"></asp:TextBox></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:left"><asp:Label ID="lbHouseOccupant" runat="server" Text="Number of House occupant"></asp:Label></td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtHouseOccupant" class="basetxt" runat="server" Width="290"></asp:TextBox></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td style="text-align:left"><asp:Button ID="btnAddOccupant" runat="server" Text="+" />
     <asp:Label ID="lbAddOccupant" runat="server" Text="Add Occupant"></asp:Label></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
     <div id="divShowFormHere"></div>
     </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   </div></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

**#divOccupantProfile**

```
<div id="divOccupantProfile">

<asp:Label ID="OPfamilyname" runat="server" Text="Family Name"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="textOPfamilyname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />

<asp:Label ID="OPfirstname" runat="server" Text="First Name"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="textOPfirstname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />

<asp:Label ID="OPmiddlename" runat="server" Text="Middle Name"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="textOPmiddlename" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />

<asp:Label ID="OPmaritalstatus" runat="server" Text="Marital Status"></asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOPmaritalstatus" runat="server" >
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Married</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Single</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Divorced</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList><br />

<asp:Label ID="OPoccupation" runat="server" Text="Occupation"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="textOPoccupation" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />

<asp:Label ID="OPrelationship" runat="server" Text="Relationship"></asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOPrelationship" runat="server" >
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Wife</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Daughter</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Son</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Father</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Mother</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>House helper</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Driver</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would handle this scenario differently. I usually have a button/icon for adding additional occupants. 
Asp.NET MVC handles these scenarios much more easily, but in Web Forms here is a link that shows you how to do it, the trick is to enable ViewState to remember every new control that you add, otherwise any post back will delete them:

> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/502251/How-to-create-controls-dynamically-in-ASP-NET-and